# Specify columns with in DoCmd.TransferText

Tags: ms-access

I have a report that exports to a CSV. It works fine, but what if I want only the first column to actually export in the file instead of everything? Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub EthosRpt_Click()
  DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)

  Dim FileName As String

  DoCmd.OpenQuery "QryEthosCSV"

  FileName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\EthosRpt.csv"
  DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "EthosData", FileName, False

  DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a new query that contains exactly the column(s) you want to export, then use this query with `DoCmd.TransferText`.